# Changing Grub2 resolution on Linux Mint 19 / Ubuntu 18.04 / derivatives

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, resolution

### Hardware

I have a 15.6-inch laptop with a UHD display (with resolution 3840 x 2160), which is a [HiDPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density#Named_pixel_densities).

282.42 PPI = Actually, an eXtra High density display according to [this calculator](https://www.sven.de/dpi/).

---

### System

Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon 64-bit. UEFI installation.

---

### Situation

I dual-boot with Windows 10 on a separate drive and choose via Grub2 what I need at that moment.

The Grub2 is by default on my hardware set to be displayed in full resolution of 3840 x 2160.

This is incredibly hard to read, practically impossible to do any other thing than press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

### Intention

I would like to set some lower resolution like 1920 x 1080 or lower depending on what would be readable.

---

### Approach

I looked at the comments of `/etc/default/grub` file, stating, excerpt:

```
# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

I simply uncommented the `GRUB_GFXMODE` line and set it to `1920x1080`.

Which after `sudo update-grub` I tested with the result being **unchanged resolution**.

So, I put hopes in the `vbeinfo` command, which was not recognized by my Grub2.

---

### Question

What am I doing wrong here?

And how do I discover all of the supported resolutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that on my system the following command works for listing supported resolutions:

```
videoinfo
```

Call it from inside Grub2 prompt, and take a photo of it (that was my approach) or remember it.

---

In my case, for some reason, the 1920 x 1080 resolution **was not in the list**.

I tried various supported resolutions, and in the end, settled for 800 x 600.